# How to globally enable ld.so secure-execution mode for all applications?

Tags: environment-variables

Quote https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages/ld.so.8.en.html#Secure-execution_mode

> Secure-execution mode
>
> For security reasons, the effects of some environment variables are voided or modified if the dynamic linker determines that the binary should be run in secure-execution mode. (For details, see the discussion of individual environment variables below.) A binary is executed in secure-execution mode if the AT_SECURE entry in the auxiliary vector (see getauxval(3)) has a nonzero value. This entry may have a nonzero value for various reasons, including:
>
> - The process's real and effective user IDs differ, or the real and effective group IDs differ. This typically occurs as a result of executing a set-user-ID or set-group-ID program.
> - A process with a non-root user ID executed a binary that conferred capabilities to the process.
> - A nonzero value may have been set by a Linux Security Module.

How could secure-execution mode be globally enabled lets say for all applications started from a limited linux user account `user`?

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard way to do this. You can write/use an LSM which sets `bprm->secureexec = 1` for all processes under the user you want, or you can patch the [dynamic linker](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=elf/dl-support.c;hb=900962f37f64c263db83ec8639847e8f6753b8d9) in a way like this:

```
--- a/elf/dl-support.c
+++ b/elf/dl-support.c
@@ -316,7 +316,7 @@ _dl_aux_init (ElfW(auxv_t) *av)
       }
   if (seen == 0xf)
     {
-      __libc_enable_secure = uid != 0 || gid != 0;
+      __libc_enable_secure = uid != 0 || gid != 0 || !!getenv ("LD_SECURE");
       __libc_enable_secure_decided = 1;
     }
 }
```

This patch adds support for a new environmental variable, `LD_SECURE`, which if set, causes the linker to act as if `AT_SECURE` was set in its auxiliary vector. I haven't tested this patch since it's so trivial, but it should do what you want. You will need to set that environmental variable for any user you want to run in secure-execution mode. Note that this is very likely to break a lot of applications.

I do have to question the utility of doing this, though. Secure execution mode is designed to protect a process executing another process across a privilege boundary. It is not a generic security feature. You should consider your threat model and try to find out exactly what you are protecting against.